# Android Studio: How to have onStop called for a video activity started with an intent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

From what I understand, onStop is called when the current activity becomes invisible, good.

But what if I want an onStop that concerns not my current activity but a video player activity started with an intent? I'd like to do this in order to show a rating form when the user is done playing a video.

```
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("https://example.com/thevideo.webm");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, videoUri);
intent.setDataAndType(videoUri, "video/webm");
startActivity(intent);

// and then onStop() for this intent created, and not for my current activity.
```

As a little bonus I would love to prevent the video from closing at the end, but rather having the user click "Done" a bit like iOS has it, and that's when onStop() would be called.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At the top of my head, you could simply start the activity in which you display the form, that would send the Activity running the video (VideoActivity) to the background and the onStop method will be called.

The second thing you can do is create a public static member of the VideoActivity class, and then from the Form Activity call its finish method e.g. VideoActivity.objectVideoActivity.finish()